# Why does jQuery DataTable show "No data available in table" when there is a populated tbody

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

So I have a table in an slim file that is populated via erb. When I initialize DataTable on it, it appends the table with a new tbody that reads "No data available in table". Here's the html.slim part

```
table#search.table.table-striped.search
  thead
    tr
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
      th Header
  tbody
  - @search_result.each do |result|
    tr
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
      td
        = result[data]
```

And here is my js:

```
var SearchPage = function() {
  this.$table = $('#search');
  this.init();
}

SearchPage.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    this.$table.DataTable({
      autoWidth: false,
      paging: false,
      info: false,
      searching: false
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  var newSearch = new SearchPage();
});
```

I'm not sure where my syntax error is. DataTable should be able to pick up data from the DOM without doing this, and as best I can tell this adheres to their documentation. What am I doing wrong?>

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was not with DataTable at all. The issue was instead with the way slim renders HTML. Having the following:

```
tbody
  @search_result.each do |result|
```

Would up rendering two tbody elements, the first one empty. DataTable was attempting to read the empty one, and produced the error.